# MDB2: Unable to bind to missing placeholder

Tags: php, mysqli, mdb2

I am trying to use Pear `MDB2` object in order to execute a query against my database, but it isn't working. Instead I am receiving an error `Unable to bind to missing placeholder` on the `execute()`. I have a sql builder function, which returns a sql statement and parameters to a store data function which also accepts an array of values to bind to the statement. 
NOTE: I substituted `$params` for `$_POST` they are both an array of form inputs. Except I validate all input store it in an object for later use by the application and then store it in the database. The database connection is MDB2.
The function `userinfo()` returns the `user` object variables.

```
public function build_sql_Insert($arry, $table)
    {
        if(!is_array($arry)){
            return false;
        }

        $types = str_repeat("s", count($arry));
        $keys = array_keys($arry);
        $values = array_values($arry);

        if ($table==="user") {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(',', $keys) . ") VALUES (".implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')).")ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
            $updates = implode(',', array_map(function($col) {
                return "$col = VALUES($col)";
            }, $keys));

            $sql .= $updates;
            return $sql;
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(',', $keys) . ") VALUES (" .
            implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')) . ")";

        return $sql;
    }
```

Store Data

```
public function storeData($sql, $cxn, $params){

        if($stmt = $cxn->prepare($sql, MDB2_PREPARE_MANIP)){
            $afft = $stmt->execute($params);
            $stmt->free();

            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

Passed user object which is returned as an array calling `userInfo()`:

```
WI_User Object
(
    [UserId:WI_User:private] => 1
    [FirstName:WI_User:private] => Natasha
    [LastName:WI_User:private] => Harris
    [Email:WI_User:private] => kevlwig@gmail.com
    [Password:WI_User:private] => $2y$10$YrYZs24ihAcRYqBROemTUuTmUQCI4l0zO52pjPGIC2PfKn/tOHC1G
    [UserPix:WI_User:private] => 
    [Status:WI_User:private] => 1
)
```

SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO user (UserId,FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,UserPix,Status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UserId = VALUES(UserId),FirstName = VALUES(FirstName),LastName = VALUES(LastName),Email = VALUES(Email),Password = VALUES(Password),UserPix = VALUES(UserPix),Status = VALUES(Status)
```

Function calling:

```
$userdata = $this->user->userInfo();
$sql = $this->build_sql_Insert($userdata, $this->moduleName);
$this->storeData($sql, $this->db, $userdata)
```

Comment: Please show the arry your passing in.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the array is dynamic ill add the class

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the array is just simple user input

Comment: You could shorten it abit: https://3v4l.org/Q5mjl

Comment: Echo out your queries, and your counts. I'm thinking when you use `array_fill(0, count($values), '?')`, you're actually getting one more placeholder than you need.

Comment: @aynber you're thinking it's an off-by-one error? didn't think about that

Comment: @LawrenceCherone a lot more cleaner thanks

Comment: @aynber i added the sql statement